# Android NDK debugging - hardware breakpoints

Tags: android, debugging, android-ndk

For my Android NDK app, I want to monitor a memory address and break when it is modified because I suspect there is a bad pointer somewhere corrupting memory.

I'm having enough trouble getting debugging working with the Android NDK as it is, and I'm wondering, are hardware breakpoints / watchpoints even supported?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11577139/gdb-hardware-breakpoint-dont-work-with-remote-debugging), where I submitted an answer that might help you.